# Can we (locally) have multiple remotes for multiple forks, and push to a branch of a different forks?

Tags: git, github

I know this is complicated and probably a stupid question, but here is the situation:

We have a main Git repo with the primary codebase that goes into production. Then we have multiple forks for different people on the team. Occasionally, someone starts working on a change, and it seems easiest for us to add one more small change to their branch on their repo and push that (e.g. if a pull request is already opened and we need to make one small addition). Since we're on the same GitHub team, we can push to others' forks of repos. Right now, we have separate directories for each fork on our local machines for this. But it would nicer if it could just be one directory and we could have multiple forks as remotes.

For example, here is how it might go:

```
git clone <my fork ssh>
git remote add upstream <main repo ssh>
git remote add teammate <teammate's repo ssh>
git checkout teammate/branchname
```

After running the last `git checkout`, it is in a "detached head" state.

A couple questions related to this are:

- is there a better way to approach this besides having multiple directories for each fork of the primary repo?
- is there any way to get it working as I've intended above?

Answer (score 3):

You can absolutely do this, it's one of Git's big wins. What you fetch or construct or discard in your own repo, and what you call anything in it, is entirely up to you.

```
git checkout -tb teammate-branchname teammate/branchname
```

will give you a local branch `teammate-branchname` tracking `teammate/branchname`.

The histories matter. What you or anyone calls them doesn't. Annotated tags by default and universal convention have the same names everywhere, but even those can be renamed locally.

Comment: This creates a branch in my fork but sets the head at where the teammate's branch is at, right? What I want to do is be able to push additional changes to their fork/branch.

Comment: The default push setup is configured to protect against newbie mistakes, say `git help config` and search for `push.default`, depending on how your teammate wants to do things `current` or `matching` or `upstream` might be best. You can also configure specific standard pushes per remote.

Comment: You can add commits to any history in your repo any time you want, whether or not you've bothered naming the tip. In the example I gave, commit your work on the teammate-branchname branch and either you push or they fetch it to their repo, using whatever name you agree on there. If there's work going on in parallel somebody's going to have to merge or rebase and you'll probably want different names for the tips (you could push to a `from-wftw` branch which they merge, or you could push it to your own repo and ask them to pull from there, all that's just ordinary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want as follows:

```
git clone <my fork ssh>
git remote add upstream <main repo ssh>
git remote add teammate <teammate's repo ssh>
git fetch teammate
git checkout -b branchname --track teammate/branchname
```

Comment: note:  be careful if the same branchname is used on multiple remotes

Comment: "be careful if the same branchname is used on multiple remotes" Why?

Comment: If you will be working with the same remote branch names on different remotes you can use something like `git checkout -b teammate_branchname --track teammate/branchname` to name your local branches after the remote name as well.

Comment: Matt, if the same branch name is used on multiple remotes it is possible for those branches to diverge with different commits on each remote.  Though they have the same name, they are different branches

Comment: And Git knows that they are different branches. The correspondence is not based on the bare name. You can set up tracking however you like (including no tracking) between a local and a remote branch quite irrespective of their bare names. There is absolutely no danger and your warning is misleading.

Comment: My warning is not based on any git issue, but user issues.  If the user has a local "master" branch the user needs to know and remember that it is tracking teammate/master and not origin/master.  If the user needs to work with both origin/master and teammate/master, it makes more sense to create two local branches named teammate-master and origin-master

Comment: I don't know if it "makes more sense" but it's a really nice idea. So that was the thing to say, not some vague Here Be Dragons warning. Even so, it's not like there is any problem finding out what is tracking what. Or, if you're like me, you don't use automatic tracking between local and remote-tracking branches; you always specify a remote and branch.

Comment: Point taken. I will try not to post vague warnings in the future.

Comment: As I said with the other answer, this creates a branch in my fork but sets the head at where the teammate's branch is at, right? What I want to do is be able to push additional changes to their fork/branch.

Comment: The command `git checkout -b teammate_branchname --track teammate/branchname` creates a local branch in your local repo that tracks the remote branch in the remote repo.  You can push additional changes by `git commit` your changes locally than `git push` (with the `teammate_branchname` branch checked out).